# Error deploying JBoss EAP 6

Tags: cxf, jboss-eap-6, maven-dependency-plugin

Currently working on getting a CXF web service up and running on JBOSS EAP 6. I currently have it running and working for the most part but every time there is a issue I get the following error:

```
[[ ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Real: name=vfs:///C:/Users/priya/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_AS_6.x1412451047498/deploy/ChatSec.war state=PreReal mode=Manual requiredState=Real: org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error during deploy: vfs:///C:/Users/priya/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_AS_6.x1412451047498/deploy/ChatSec.war
            at org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException.rethrowAsDeploymentException(DeploymentException.java:49) [:2.2.2.GA]
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:185) [:2.2.2.GA]
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.2.GA]
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.2.GA]
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.2.GA]
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.2.GA]
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.2.GA]
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.2.GA]
            at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
            at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
            at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
            at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
            at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
            at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
            at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
            at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
            at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
            at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
            at org.jboss.profileservice.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:154) [:0.2.2]
            at org.jboss.system.tools.ProfileServiceToolsFacade.addURI(ProfileServiceToolsFacade.java:233) [:6.1.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.system.tools.LegacyDeploymentScannerAdapter.addURL(LegacyDeploymentScannerAdapter.java:140) [:6.1.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.system.tools.DeploymentScanner.addURL(DeploymentScanner.java:91) [:6.1.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.system.tools.DeploymentScanner.addURL(DeploymentScanner.java:83) [:6.1.0.Final]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.7.0_67]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [:1.7.0_67]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [:1.7.0_67]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [:1.7.0_67]
            at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157) [:6.0.0.GA]
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96) [:6.0.0.GA]
            at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) [:6.0.0.GA]
            at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:271) [:6.0.0.GA]
            at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:670) [:6.0.0.GA]
            at org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerWrapper.invoke(MBeanServerWrapper.java:138) [:6.1.0.Final]
            at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487) [:1.7.0_67]
            at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97) [:1.7.0_67]
            at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328) [:1.7.0_67]
            at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420) [:1.7.0_67]
            at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848) [:1.7.0_67]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.7.0_67]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [:1.7.0_67]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [:1.7.0_67]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [:1.7.0_67]
            at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322) [:1.7.0_67]
            at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177) [:1.7.0_67]
            at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174) [:1.7.0_67]
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.7.0_67]
            at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173) [:1.7.0_67]
            at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556) [:1.7.0_67]
            at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811) [:1.7.0_67]
            at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670) [:1.7.0_67]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [:1.7.0_67]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [:1.7.0_67]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [:1.7.0_67]
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Neither any mapped-name/lookup/jndi-name specified nor any ResourceProvider could process resource-env-ref named env/org.apache.cxf.binding.AbstractBaseBindingFactory/bus of type org.apache.cxf.Bus
            at org.jboss.switchboard.mc.resource.provider.ResourceEnvRefProvider.provide(ResourceEnvRefProvider.java:119) [:1.0.0-alpha-15]
            at org.jboss.switchboard.mc.resource.provider.ResourceEnvRefProvider.provide(ResourceEnvRefProvider.java:43) [:1.0.0-alpha-15]
            at org.jboss.switchboard.mc.JndiEnvironmentProcessor.process(JndiEnvironmentProcessor.java:68) [:1.0.0-alpha-15]
            at org.jboss.switchboard.mc.deployer.AbstractSwitchBoardDeployer.process(AbstractSwitchBoardDeployer.java:119) [:1.0.0-alpha-15]
            at org.jboss.switchboard.mc.deployer.WebEnvironmentSwitchBoardDeployer.internalDeploy(WebEnvironmentSwitchBoardDeployer.java:66) [:1.0.0-alpha-15]
            at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.2.GA]
            at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.2.GA]
            ... 70 more]]}
```

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>ChatSecProject</display-name>


  <display-name>ChatSec</display-name>    
    <context-param>
        <description>Spring configuration file</description>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/test.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>                                                                            



<!--

  <display-name>ChatSec</display-name>    
    <context-param>
        <description>Spring configuration file</description>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/prod.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>    

        --> 

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.bravestorm.center.jws.util.ChatContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <description>Spring Loader</description>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.jboss.spring.vfs.context.VFSXmlWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>folders</param-name>
    <param-value>1037953118578197474@PS</param-value>
  </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>timeGap</param-name>
    <param-value>1@PS,0</param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Please check this post he was getting almost same error as yours. [SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227367/impossible-to-inject-jms-queueconnectionfactory-in-jboss-6-1-0-with-resource-ann)

Comment: I didn't get exact answer for it. I want to know why I get this error when I start the server                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Neither any mapped-name/lookup/jndi-name specified nor any ResourceProvider could process resource-env-ref named env/org.apache.cxf.binding.AbstractBaseBindingFactory/bus of type org.apache.cxf.Bus